# How do we make a crystal report print only specific fields based off of the user running the report?

Tags: security, crystal-reports, data-security

We use a construction software, Viewpoint. We need a report to print the GL Accounts associated only with the user running the report. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I could easily and efficiently achieve this? My "last-resort alternative" is just creating separate reports for each GL that pulls only that GL's info.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the accounts are associated to the user. If there is a link, you can simply create a user parameter that asks for the user name. Then in the record select of the report you only pull accounts that match the user name in the parameter.
So, for example your parameter is called `{?userName}`. In the Record Select the formula would something like `{Accounts.Salesman} = {?userName}`, where {Accounts.Salesman} would be the field that links the user with the account.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the response, campagnolo_1! I am discussing it with our software company now to figure out if that linking is even an option. The data is coming from tables that are more unrelated than related. So it may be a bit of a hassle to create that link. I will post the solution.

Comment: I think it will be your best bet if you can figure out the linking.

Comment: I definitely think that'd be best, but we've had major disasters with linking in the past, so making separate reports that are restricted per department might be faster. So I am waiting to see what our software company has to say about it. I'm hoping others have wanted something similar so they have a solution right away or know the linking right away.

Comment: Do you know what database type is used (SQL, Access, FoxPro, etc.)? Good luck and keep us posted.

Comment: Sure do, it's SQL. I know I can create a stored procedure that should resolve issues linking different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current user name and use it to filter the records in your report. There are 2 ways to do this :

create a parameter, hide it and automatically fill the value. You
    will need a special viewer for this scenario. Let me know if this is
    what would you prefer I can give you some links. If you leave the
    parameter visible the user can insert any value and view any records

use an UFL . For example this one:
    http://www.viksoe.dk/code/u2lwin32.htm provides a function LoginName
    which will return currently logged user. There are other UFLs which
    support similar functionality, check if your company is already
    using something . This one is free. You need to register the UFL on
    each system which will run the report . Once registered the
    available functions will become available for formulas.

I personally prefer the viewer solution because it is more flexible and will cover other scenarios too. However if you need just the username UFL will be a better approach.